# Installation of openjdk 7

Tags: system-installation, openjdk

I am installing openjdk-7 on my Ubuntu 10.04 server
But I find it to be difficult.

I am new to Ubuntu.
I have installed the python software properties as suggested by some advice I saw online
and have uncommented these two lines:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner0
```

Also i have done these two successfully:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk/ppa
apt-get update
```

`apt-get install openjdk-7` is not working as I expect.

Comment: `apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`, this is the command for you to install jdk.....for other options try pressing `tab` after `openjdk-7-`

Comment: @VineetMenon - if you moved that to an answer I would upvote it

Comment: @aking1012, :D.

Comment: Big Thanks on teh 'update altertives...." :)

Answer (score 8):

The correct command is `apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`, this is the command for you to install jdk,

for other options, from which I mean `doc`, `jre`, `source`, try pressing tab after `openjdk-7-` and apt will autocomplete it for you..

Answer (score 2):

The following command should install jdk, jre ..

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

In case you had previous version of the java installed you have to update your java configuration and set openjdk-7-jre to be your auto (default) using the following command.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: You may need to run `sudo update-alternatives --config javac` as well